# Vectors and their properties

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to face my linear algebra exam in next wednesday.so i found this question from practice question paper and i dont know how to prove this.
I want clear proving steps for find thi s k. question is

{(k, −1, −1),(−1, k, −1),(−1, −1, k)}

if the above spanning set is linearly dependent then how to find the k?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know how much you know about vector space. Try to add more details about your progress and where you stuck.But as a beginner,i think you deserve a answer as this an elementary problem and this help you to think about other problems. 3 vectors are L. D if they lies on a same plane.Here it's really easy to see $k=-1$ works fine.
\begin{align}
1(-1, -1, -1) +1(-1, -1, -1) -2(-1, -1, -1) =0 \end{align}

In general, you have to find a non trivial linear combination that produce the zero vector on the RHS.

Or, write down 3 vectors as 3 columns of a matrix and try to find the value of $k$ for which determinant is zero.